# JAXB/MOXy: Wrong namespace for element

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am using MOXy and classes which belong to different namespaces, but MOXy always adds the wrong namespace to the referenced object. Why is this simple example not working as expected?

**AtomLink.java:**

```
package org.atom;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class AtomLink {

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String rel;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String href;

    public AtomLink() {
    }

    public AtomLink(String rel, String href) {
        this.rel = rel;
        this.href = href;
    }

}
```

**Person.java**

```
package org.example;

import org.atom.AtomLink;

@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Person {

    @XmlElement
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement
    protected AtomLink link;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, AtomLink link) {
        this.name = name;
        this.link = link;
    }

}
```

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", xmlns={
    @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", prefix = "atom")}, elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package org.atom;
```

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.test.org", xmlns={
    @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.test.org", prefix = "test")}, elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED) 
package org.example;
```

**Test-Code:**

```
Person person = new Person("Test", new AtomLink("self", "http://www.test.org/person/Test"));
try {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { Person.class }, null);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**The result:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test:person xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:test="http://www.test.org">
    <test:name>Test</test:name>
    <test:link atom:rel="self" atom:href="http://www.test.org/person/Test"/>
</test:person>
```

**But I am expecting:**

```xml
...
    <atom:link atom:rel="self" atom:href="http://www.test.org/person/Test"/>
...
```

Why is MOXy not recognising that the class AtomLink belongs to a different namespace? As you can see, only the element's namespace is wrong, but its attributes are assigned to the right namespace.

## Update

I have done the following changes as proposed. The classes look as follows:

**AtomLink.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "link")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class AtomLink {

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String rel;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String href;

    public AtomLink() {
    }

}
```

**Person.java:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Person {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElementRef
    private AtomLink link;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, AtomLink link) {
        this.name = name;
        this.link = link;
    }

}
```

The result is an invalid XML document, which defines n0 as the targetNamespace for the link element, but its attributes are assigned to my atom-prefix.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test:person xmlns:test="http://www.test.org" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom>
    <test:name>Test</test:name>
    <ns0:link atom:rel="self" atom:href="http://www.test.org/person/Test"/>
</test:person>
```

Extending the "http://www.test.org" namespace with an atom-entry is not a solution, because that results always in a namespace declaration even if no atom-element is present in the XML document.

## Update2

If I use the Java internal JAXB-Implementation everythings works as expected... There must be an error in the MOXy implementation.

Comment: Yes, I believe you hit a MOXy bug, so I reported it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400545

Comment: @MichałPolitowski - Thank you for entering the bug, we should be able to get a fix out soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. This fix will be very useful for my current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were experiencing was a [bug](http://bugs.eclipse.org/400536) in MOXy that has now been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.4.2 and 2.5.0 streams.  You can download a nightly build from the following location as of February 13th 2013.

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

In terms of the correct mapping see the [answer given by Michał Politowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14828386/383861).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have downloaded and tested your new version (org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.5.0.v20130213-32655ee.jar). The bug is solved, everything works as expected. Excellent work!

Answer (score 1):

This is the way JAXB works. The namespace (just like its name, so it's quite natural) of a local element is specified by the attributes of its `@XmlElement` annotation.

If you want `AtomLink`, not `Person`,  to decide these (both namespace and name, since they go together), you have to make it `@XmlRootElement` and use `@XmlElementRef` in Person.

If you want to stay with `@XmlElement`

```
@XmlElement(namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
private AtomLink link;
```

is the way to go.